# Is it possible to run a Zapier zap retrospectively?

Tags: evernote, trello, zapier

I created a zap in Zapier that adds new Evernote notes from a particular notebook to a particular list in Trello. It does this for my new notes but I want to do this for my existing notes in this notebook too. I managed to get three in when doing the test zap when I set it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't. This feature has been on their roadmap for a while but isn't yet implemented.

What you could try however is to temporarily move your old notes to another notebook and put them back in the original one.

It should trigger your zap.